# python: rename files based on modified date + iterator

Tags: python

I've got a directory of files that is constantly being added to. Some times there are several files that go in per day, but the number might vary. I'd like to periodically run a script that scans the files and renames them based on the date the file was created + some iterator if there was more than one file for the day.

Here's what I've got so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import datetime
target = "/target_dir"
os.chdir(target)
allfiles = os.listdir(target)
for filename in allfiles:
        if not os.path.isfile(filename):
                continue
        t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
        v= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
        x = v.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        loop = 1
        iterator = 1
        temp_name = x + "_" + str(iterator)
        while loop:
                if not os.path.exists(temp_name + '.mp4'):
                        os.rename(filename, temp_name + '.mp4')
                        loop = 0
                else:
                        temp_name = x + '_' + str(iterator)
                        iterator+=1
```

And that seems to work but if I run the script a second time it changes the filenames prematurely (i.e. date1-1.mp4 becomes date1-2.mp4, etc)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra check `if filename == tempname: continue`

Comment: Thanks, should have thought of that!

Answer (score 2):

When you have renamed files the first time, you then have a folder of files: *date1-1.mp4, date2-1.mp4*, as you say.

On the second run the line `if not os.path.exists(temp_name + '.mp4'):` will say that a file *date1-1.mp4* already exists - namely the file itself - and will then continue the loop until an unused filename is available: *date1-2.mp4*.

My solution was as follows: (essentially equivalent to Hans' answer)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import datetime
target = + "/target_dir"
os.chdir(target)
allfiles = os.listdir(target)
for filename in allfiles:
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        continue
    t = os.path.getmtime(filename)
    v= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t)
    x = v.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    loop = 1
    iterator = 1
    temp_name = x + "_" + str(iterator) + '.mp4'

    while filename != temp_name:
        if not os.path.exists(temp_name):
            os.rename(filename, temp_name)
            filename = temp_name
        else:
            iterator+=1
            temp_name = x + '_' + str(iterator) + '.mp4'
```